# After unclean shutdown, ownCloud keeps responding with HTTP Error 500

Tags: raspbian, owncloud

My Raspbian-based ownCloud server suffered a power outage the other day. Since then I haven’t been able to use ownCloud: in the browser I just get a blank page that doesn’t seem to finish loading, DAVdroid and the desktop sync client complain about getting an HTTP Error 500 (Internal server error).

I can’t even get to the ownCloud admin UI. The syslog has no entries which appear suspicious. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic guide to ownCloud troubleshooting is on the [official web site](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/issues/general_troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-web-server-and-php-problems).

**ownCloud log files** are in `/var/www/owncloud/data/owncloud.log` was empty in my case.

**PHP5 error logs** are disabled by default (at least on Raspbian). You need to enable them in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` by setting `log_errors` to On and setting the path for the logfile in `error_log`. After that you need to restart your web server in order for the changes to take effect—I skipped this whole step.

**Apache error logs** are stored in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (on Raspbian—the path may vary wildly between distributions). Logs are rotated on restart, or every 24 hours, with the previous log being renamed to `error.log.1`, the log before that being gzipped and named `error.log.2.gz` and so on, for 10+ logs. They can be viewed like this:

```
sudo less /var/log/apache2/error.log
sudo less /var/log/apache2/error.log.1
sudo zcat /var/log/apache2/error.log.2.gz | less
```

(note the different command for gzipped logs).

The Apache error logs had a lot of lines like these:

> [Sat Mar 04 14:32:15.682697 2017] [:error] [pid 12325] [client 10.15.1.19:56016] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '41' (T_LNUMBER), expecting ')' in /var/www/owncloud/3rdparty/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Crypt/Hash.php on line 385

Digging down a bit further into the history, indeed it turned out that this error had started appearing when the system first came up after the power outage, which hints at file system corruption.

The file in question appears to be part of the ownCloud installation, thus I figured the easiest way would be to reinstall the ownCloud package (I had chosen the deb path).

Since ownCloud had since released a new version, 9.1.4 (my server is still on 9.1.3), the reinstall failed because the original package was no longer available at its old location.

I therefore decided to risk it and run the upgrade, which I figured would restore the missing file in the same way. (A reinstall probably would have worked as well, and restored the service more quickly.)

After the upgrade, at least ownCloud greeted me with a notice saying it was in maintenance mode. The following commands completed the upgrade:

```
sudo -u www-data php /var/www/owncloud/occ maintenance:mode --off
sudo -u www-data php /var/www/owncloud/occ upgrade
```

(note the path to `occ` must be provided, else it won’t be found).

After that, I still needed to log on with an admin account, go to Apps and re-enable my apps again.

And the server is back from the dead.